# Only date datas show up when using the insert function to add a specific time information into a database

Tags: sql, kingbase

I'm trying to insert a full integral time data into a database by using the function "insert",the code is as below

```
insert into tmp_zgn_huaxc_20220518 (OPERID, BEGINTIME, ENDTIME)
values ('50310',
        to_date('28-05-2022 13:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
        to_date('28-05-2022 17:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

the result shows successfully，but only a part of the data are show up，the others are missing.The result is as below.

| operid | begintime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 52626 | 2022-05-28 00:00:00 | 2022-05-28 00:00:00 |

There are three DBMS I have tried (postgresql / opengauss / kingbase ),the result is the same.

Comment: I'd try the ANSI SQL standard way `timestamp'2022-05-28 13:00:00'`.

Comment: You should use the format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" instead of "dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss"